# After re directing to same page flashMessanger is not showing zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to redirect to the same page using this function in Zend Framework but I am not getting the Flash message I set in this function Somebody Please help me

but if clicking other resut after execution of this code I am able to see that error message.

Thanks in advance....

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    if( $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages()) {
        $this->view->message = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages();
    }
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')){
        $surfaceReservation = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Model_Reservation')->findOneById($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        if($surfaceReservation) $surfaceReservation->delete();
        $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage('Deleted Successfully');
    }
    $this->_redirect('/arena/surface/reservation');
}
```

Comment: I dont know if this is the issue but as per the [zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger) you have to start the session `Zend_Session::start()` if you need the user to see the messages on the next request

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your target action is assigning the messages to its view.

```
if( $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages()) {
    $this->view->message = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages();
}
```